# Search Data for matching row/array

Tags: google-sheets

I want to search a set of data to see if it contains a matching set of values eg.

```
+------+------+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
+------+------+------+------+
| A    | B    | C    | D    |
+------+------+------+------+
```

would match the last row in

```
+------+------+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
+------+------+------+------+
| B    | C    | D    | A    |
| A    | D    | B    | C    |
| A    | B    | B    | D    |
| D    | C    | B    | A    |
| A    | B    | C    | D    |
+------+------+------+------+
```

A boolean return would be fine.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: So far I've tried concatenating the 2 data groups individually and then searching for the key that way but for some reason it fails even though I can see they contain  identical strings. The output can just be a count as it will only match once. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Assumptions

1. Columns to check: A:D
2. Values to check are in F1:I1
3. Result in K1 - boolean

## Code

```
=NOT(ISERROR(
    QUERY({ArrayFormula(A1:A&B1:B&C1:C&D1:D)},
    "select * where Col1='"&JOIN("",F1:I1)&"'",0)
        )
     )
```

## Picture

[image]

Comment: Very nice. Thanks for the help.